# Obter valor de children e props no React

Tags: javascript, react

Preciso obter o `children` de um componente e também suas *props*. Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Exemplo:

```
<ElementPai value="text1" title="text2" colletion={valorArray}>
       <ElementFilho1/>
       <ElementFilho2/>
</ElementPai>

function ElementPai({children}){
       console.log(children);
       console.log(props); // <-- Não sei como acessar esta informação
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em React, `children` é sempre uma *prop*. Veja:

```js
function App(props) {
  console.log(Object.keys(props)); // Veja que `children` é uma prop.

  return <div>{props.children}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App>
    <h1>Olá, mundo!</h1>
  </App>,
  document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Portanto, se você quiser acessar todo o objeto `prop`, deverá deixar de usar a desestruturação:

```js
function ElementPai(props){
  console.log(props.children);
  console.log(props); // <-- Agora você tem as _props_. Sempre teve, aliás. :)
}
```

Você ainda pode usar a desestruturação para acessar algumas *props* específicas, assim como você estava fazendo com a *prop* `children`. Veja:

```js
function ElementPai({ children, someOtherProp, andAnotherProp }){
  console.log(children);
  console.log(someOtherProp);
  console.log(andAnotherProp);
}
```

Basta lembrar que `children` é uma *prop*. :-)

---

Leia [esta documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao#Desestrutura%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_objeto) para saber mais sobre a desestruturação.

Comment: Olá isso mesmo, muito obrigado